# black screen with mouse cursor after passphrase

Tags: linux

I'm new to this world of Linux and know very little if anything.  My computer is an ACER (but I don't know what year it is I think it will be 10 or 20 years ago I have no idea).
Through the "Anonguide" by Anonymus (2014 version) I installed Debian using Unetbootin installing everything and only via USB stick also following the encryption processes and in fact the stick is encrypted.  The installation was successful but when I start the computer I click F12, then click my USB stick it gives me "welcom to GRUB" and I am in GNU GRUB version 2.06-3~dev11u5.

Then I see 3 sentences that say:
-Debian Gnu/linux"
-Advanced option for Debian GNU/Linux

- Windows 10 (on /Dev/sdb1)
  I then press enter on the first sentence "Debian Gnu/Linux" and I find myself after these 2 messages:
- "Linux 5.10.0-23-686-pae ..."
- "Loading initial ramdisk..."
  After about 1 minute, this black screen loads me with the following message:
- Volume group "Debian-vg" not found
- Cannot process volume group Debian-vg
- Volume group "Debian-vg" not found
- Cannot process volume group Debian-vg
- Please unlock disk sda5_crypt:

I enter my passphrase and it gives me the correct one.  From there a series of writings start and after a few seconds it gives me a black screen with only the invisible mouse cursor... I'm stuck and I don't know how to continue the guide.  It should give me a white screen with the Debian login window according to the guide I'm following.  I've tried repeating everything from the beginning but nothing is all the same.  I made sure to set the USB stick to Fat32 before starting (I formatted it of course).
What should I do??  I hope for your help please.

Sorry if maybe I speak wrong but I speak Italian and not English, I'm using Google translate XD[image: screenshot][image]
[image]
[image]